# Trying to rehide an HTML element through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, setattribute

I have a code here that unhides a form element in the HTML when a button is pressed by setting the style attribute to ""

```
q = document.getElementById('delivery'); q.setAttribute('style',"")
```

Is it possible to undo this action when another button is pressed? (to re-hide the element)

I tried using `q.setAttribute('style',"hide")` but it doesn't work for some reason.

I'm reasonably new to javascript and programming in general, so any help would be appreciated

Comment: How is it hidden in the first place?

Comment: It's hidden with 
<form name="deliveryinfo" id="delivery" style="display:none">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting style attribute to null will not hide the content. Use this instead to hide the div

```
document.getElementById('delivery').style.display = "none"
```

and to show

```
document.getElementById('delivery').style.display = "block"
```

Answer (score 1):

To hide an element use

```
q = document.getElementById('delivery');
q.style.display='none';
```

Again to make it visible use

```
q = document.getElementById('delivery');
q.style.display='block';
```

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
q.style.display = "none";
```

it will hide your button as you wished to do. and to show button again:

```
q.style.display = "block";
```